# Django properly remove treebeard

Tags: django

I was using Django treebeard, which then i decided i no longer need it and just went a head reformed the class model that was using it and deleted my migrations and cash files, however my app keeps trying to use django treebeard and throw and error how i can tell my App to actually start fresh.

P.S i dont care about the database inside, i just dont want to write the app all over again.

This how it looked before :

```
from django.db import models
from vessels.models import Vessel
from treebeard.mp_tree import MP_Node

# Create your models here.


class Component(MP_Node):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(
        Vessel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vessel_components')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is how i want it to be :

```
class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(
        Vessel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vessel_components')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

what other files/folder do i need to delete ?

Error :

```
type object 'Component' has no attribute 'get_tree'
```

Comment: please share the error..

Comment: @JSRB Updated and the error is included

Comment: looks to me that somewhere your code is looking for the attribute which it can't find any longer due to your class updates. Did you already uninstall it? Also where (file/line) does that error occur?

Comment: @JSRB exactly, i removed it from installed up in settings, and deleted migrations and the database but dont really know what else i can delete, this is happening at the admin panel when trying to just view the components